# Acceder a ViewData en una vista Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Estoy haciendo una lista de estudiantes para mostrarla en una vista Razor mediante ViewData.

controlador

```
using ViewData.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ViewBag.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Student        
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();
            studentList.Add(new Student() { StudentName = "Bill" });
            studentList.Add(new Student() { StudentName = "Steve" });
            studentList.Add(new Student() { StudentName = "Ram" });

            ViewData["students"] = studentList;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Clase estudiante

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ViewData.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

vista

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>students</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            @foreach (var std in ViewData["students"] as IList<Student>)
            {
                <li>
                    @std.StudentName
                </li>
            }
        </ul>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

en la vista quiero recorrer la vista pero me indica que en `@foreach (var std in ViewData["students"] as IList<Student>)` Student no me lo está reconociendo. Que puede ser?

Comment: Recomendación utilizar la vista tipada. Envía el objeto studentList. O por algo en particular utilizas ViewData/ViewBag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no tienes una referencia al namespace de la clase Student.

Tienes dos opciones:

- Añadir una directiva using en la vista:

  @using ViewData.Models
- Añadir el namespace ViewData.Models en el web.config como namespace a incluir en las vistas Razor:

```html
    <system.web.webPages.razor>
      <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
          .....
          <add namespace="MVC_CSharp.Models"/>
        </namespaces>
      </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario usar el `ViewData`, en la vista debes hacer referencia al modelo que estás utilizando, basta con regresar la lista que generas de estudiantes usando `return View(studentList);`:

Código del `Controller`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();
    studentList.Add(new Student() { StudentName = "Bill" });
    studentList.Add(new Student() { StudentName = "Steve" });
    studentList.Add(new Student() { StudentName = "Ram" });

    return View(studentList);
}
```

Código del `View`:

```
@model IEnumerable<Student>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>students</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <li>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentName)
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Nota que al inicio del `View` estarás utilizando como modelo una colección de la clase `Student`, justo con `@model IEnumerable<Student>`, de esta forma, al ya tener un `IEnumerable` ya lo puedes recorrer directamente con el `foreach`.

Comment: Aún y cuando la propuesta es la mejor práctica, me parece que no responde directamente a la pregunta plantada. En ocasiones es necesario o justificable el uso de ViewData, ViewBag, etc.

Comment: @KodiakMx ¿existe alguna justificación en la pregunta planteada  para usar ViewData en lugar de interacción a través del modelo?